# Web audio player takes time to play a song

Tags: python, django, audio

I have made a basic online music player in django. When I ran it on the localhost, the response was fast when I clicked on any song or clicked the next/prev button. I have deployed it on pythonanywhere and the response is so slow. I think it takes time to first download the song from the server.

But when I see other online music player, their response is so fast. What can be done to make response time for my app fast? The songs are stored in the database as a file and the files are stored in the media section.

Here is the link to the music player: [online music player](http://shivam123.pythonanywhere.com/)

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Song(models.Model):
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='/',default = "null")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from models import Song
def home(request):
    song = Song.objects.all()
    context = {"songs":song} 
    return render(request,'music/base.html',context)
```

Comment: Saw your `next()` function which contains so much unnecessary code. This might not be the reason for you elapsed play. but check that code once

Comment: Could you post the relevant parts of the code here instead of just linking to your site? Where are the audio files coming from? If you were loading them from your computer during testing but over a network connection on the live site that could be part of the reason it takes longer.

Comment: I think this is very broad question. 1) source needed to check where is the bottleneck 2) question should be related to some more concrete issues 3) I don't think that including js into index.html is the nice idea at first place, same as hard-coding tracks into js.

Comment: @Sam: The audio files are stored in the database as a file and the files are stored in media directory. I too think its because of the network connection.

Comment: What sort of a database are you storing them in? Generally solutions like SQL or MySQL aren't ideal for media streaming. Give [Google Big Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/) a look.

Comment: Typically online players use a streaming protocol so they can start playing as soon as the first bit of the music file arrives. They don't download the whole file first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Maybe too late but in my opinion there are maybe the reasons for slow response:

- debug on, so you are serving media files via Django itself
- you need to use external server for media (for example amazon S3)
- there are ineffective database queries ?

So basically you can simulate slow response in Chrome debug panel
And there is also great tool for debug such as [debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar)